# WCF Session Maintenance

Tags: wcf

I am new to WCF i am trying to implement WCF Session Management but i am not clear about how to implement the session in WCF

**This is my CODE**

```
<wsHttpBinding>
   <binding name="wsHttpBinding">
      <reliableSession enabled="true" />
   </binding>
</wsHttpBinding>

[ServiceContract(Namespace="http://Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples", 
SessionMode=SessionMode.Required)]
  public interface IMyService
  {
    ...
  }
```

**This is not working...session is not maintained in my project**

Now i wanted to  know whether am missing anything or whether i need to add anything else in client or server side???? or this alone is enough to implement the session in my project???

It will be of great help if someone provide some ideas,suggestions,or sample code for implementing my task...

Answer (score 0):

When you implement your IMyService in a class and a client connects to your service every client gains a new instance of your class.
There is a little example, that might help you: 
http://www.devx.com/architect/Article/40665

Answer (score 0):

How your service will behave depends not just on the SessionMode specified for the ServiceContract, but also on the InstanceContextMode under which your service implementation runs (controlled by the InstanceContextMode property of the ServiceBehavior). There is a helpful table [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.sessionmode.aspx) which tells you what to expect with the various combinations of these settings.

If this doesn't help solve your problem, please explain more specifically what behaviour you are expecting and what you are seeing.

Comment: More than one client will contact the above said service and the service has to deliver the required information that client wants.

For example: The service will hold a DOM object,here DOM means a database object which will have say Employee information.Each client will ask for different information from the DOM object,and our service has to deliver the information.Our servvice should not goto Database each time when the client calls,so for this we need to implement session management in service(WCF).

It will be of great help if its possible to provide some ideas,suggestions,or sample code